# Vsphere Center 6.7 lost administrator password

Tags: vmware, vsphere

Probably stupid question but my eyes hurts from looking at 100+ pages already and nothing of them really works.

I have test VMware vCenter Server 6.7 but I can't recall the administrator password on the console. I have root account on the underlying server where vSphere is hosted (OS is VMware Photon/Linux)
Is there a way to reset the VMware vCenter administrator password from root?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following:

root@vcenter [ ~ ]# /usr/lib/vmware-vmdir/bin/vdcadmintool

==================
Please select:
0. exit

1. Test LDAP connectivity
2. Force start replication cycle
3. Reset account password
4. Set log level and mask
5. Set vmdir state
6. Get vmdir state
7. Get vmdir log level and mask
   ==================